# Какой знак ставить после перечисления?

Tags: пунктуация

*Группа «Черкизово» производит и доставляет продукцию по двум основным сегментам: мясопереработка и птицеводство(,) а перевозки осуществляются как внутри городов в виде конечной доставки в розничные магазины, так и между регионами России.*

После слова "птицеводства" нужна 1) тире, 2) запятая, 3) запятая и тире?

Answer (score 3):

Стоит запятая - и очень хорошо: ненавязчивый знак.

Варианты с тире и зап-тире ничем не обоснованы: отпадают. (И нельзя объяснить почему, нет такого правила. Есть правило об обобщающем слове после перечисления, требующем постановки тире,  но у нас не тот случай.)

**[§ 34.](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=95)**

> Обобщающее слово, стоящее после однородных членов, отделяется от них
> знаком тире: *Поручни, компасы, бинокли, всякие приборы и даже высокие
> пороги кают — всё это было медное* (Пауст.); *И эти поездки, и наши с
> ней разговоры — всё проникнуто было щемящей, безысходной тоской*
> (Бек.).
>
> Если перед обобщающим словом, отделенным от однородных членов
> посредством тире, имеется вводное слово, то запятая перед вводным
> словом опускается: *В вестибюле, в коридоре, в кабинетах — словом,
> всюду толпились люди* (Поп.).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, желание поставить тире навеяно [Лопатиным](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=96):

> § 35. Тире ставится после перечисления однородных членов, если перечислением предложение не заканчивается: Повсюду: в клубе, на улицах, на скамейках у ворот, в домах — происходили шумные разговоры

Однакой, в данном случае перечисление стоит в **конце** простого предложения, поэтому я бы это правило в нашем случае не применял.

Попутно еще несколько замечаний.

1. Доставлять продукцию **по адресам** — корректно, а **по сегментам** — звучит смешно. Думаю правильней будет: "производит и доставляет продукцию в двух основных сегментах".
2. Имена перечиляемых объектов должны стоять в том же падеже, что и обобщающее слово.
3. "Перевозки в виде доставки". Не думаю, что такое допустимо. Возможно, "включая доставку"?

*Группа «Черкизово» производит и доставляет продукцию **в** двух основных сегментах: мясопереработк**е** и птицеводств**е**, а перевозки осуществляются как внутри городов, включая доставку в розничные магазины, так и между регионами России.*

Comment: Смотрите комментарий ниже, в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Из Справочника по русскому языку Розенталя (Орфография и пунктуация):

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103

> 8. Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а
>      после — тире: *Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в оправе, записная книжка,
>      часы, фотографический аппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об
>      интересном госте? (Пришв.); Везде: над головой, под ногами и рядом с
>      тобой — живёт, грохочет, торжествуя свои победы, железо (М. Г.).*

К этому пункту есть важная оговорка с примерами:

> **Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения
>   требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится,
>   или опускается.** *Ср.: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то:
>   пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот,
>   великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие (Сол.)* — запятая
>   закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с;
>   *Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие
>   произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только
>   небольшие безделушки (Г.)* — запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.

Из этого следует, что *запятая* в нашем примере обязательна - для присоединения второго предложения через "а", причём второй пример из справочника (*без тире*) явно ближе к нашему случаю.

Answer (score 0):

**Группа «Черкизово» производит и доставляет продукцию по двум основным сегментам — мясопереработка и птицеводство, а перевозки осуществляются как внутри городов в виде конечной доставки в розничные магазины, так и между регионами России.**

Это **пояснительная конструкция** в конце первого  предложения в составе ССП, обособленная с помощью тире, запятая же ставится  перед вторым предложением.

Здесь **нет обобщающего слова,** так как падеж не согласован.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Рассмотрим пример: Предприятие производит **продукцию двух видов — мясную и молочную,** а перевозки осуществляет/перевозки осуществляются...".

Здесь можно считать, что *продукцию двух видов* — это **обобщающее слово**, но и для этого случая у Розенталя есть объяснение:

Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, **а тире или ставится, или опускается.** Ср.: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие (Сол.) — запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с; Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) — **запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103

Таким образом,  конечное тире перед запятой не ставится, если запятая относится **к структуре сложного или осложненного однородными членами предложения.**

Comment: Согласен, что запятая лучше, чем двоеточие, но как же без  согласования по падежу?

Comment: Тире лучше, чем  двоеточие? А для пояснительных конструкций, обособленных тире,  согласование необязательно, в отличие от обобщающих слов. Например, У Розенталя: Разговор шёл один — о погоде;

Comment: Да, тире лучше, чем двоеточие. Пояснительная конструкция, можно добавить "а именно": *по двум сегментам, (а именно по)мясопереработке и птицеводству.*

Comment: Всегда есть связь с определяемым словом: разговор один — разговор о погоде. Производит по двум сегментам — производит по мясопереработке и птицеводству.  Канцеляризм махровый, конечно, он-то и путает.Скажите, например, "производит продукцию двух видов — мясную и  молочную". Сразу видно, что без согласования с опредляемым словом не обойтись.

Comment: Так если это пояснение, тире опускать нельзя. Я сам задавал вопрос по этому поводу, вы все видели.

Comment: "Когда это было, когда это было,
Во сне? Наяву?
Во сне, наяву, по волне моей памяти
Я поплыву..."  Максим, перемещение во времени требует значительных энергетических затрат.  Задайте вопрос заново.

Comment: _Вчера — в пятницу..._ Этот! А вы что подумали? Кстати, а смысл отвечать? Человек, задавший этот вопрос, уже 5 лет не заходил.

Comment: Разве дело в человеке?  Мы не только для него отвечаем, у нас большая аудитория.  А вопрос важный!  Кстати, ваш комментарий в этой теме, что мне думать-то?

Answer (score 0):

На основной вопрос уже ответили, хочу добавить комментарии к замечаниям в ответе пользователя М_Г (т.к. для комментария под ответом слишком много символов, оформляю в качестве ответа).

**1-й пункт.** Я бы не использовал такие слова, но если выражаться вашими, то скорее то, что вы предлагаете 1-м пунктом вашего замечания больше похоже на нечто, что может вызывать смех. В источнике все написано достаточно корректно, возможно, не лучшая формулировка, но логика не нарушается. У предприятия есть два сегмента (отрасль=ветвь=специализация=направление деятельности), в рамках каждого из которых существуют два бизнес-процесса: производство и доставка продукции. Смысловой посыл такой. Родовое понятие (сегмент), а далее видовые (мясопереработка и птицеводство). Т.е. два последних представляют разновидности первого. Далее - во второй части предложения - происходит детализация процесса перевозки.
В вашем же варианте ("Доставлять продукцию по адресам — корректно") они и производят продукцию в сегментах, и там же доставляют. В вашем варианте по смыслу под сегментом должна пониматься некая территория. Теперь перефразируем, используя вашу семантику, помещенную в форму одного, наиболее подходящего по смыслу обозначенного слова "территория". "Группа «Черкизово» производит и доставляет продукцию по двум основным ТЕРРИТОРИЯМ: мясопереработка и птицеводство(,) а перевозки осуществляются как внутри городов в виде конечной доставки в розничные магазины, так и между регионами России." Теперь подставьте вместо "территориям" "направлениям деятельности" - сами все увидите.
Еще раз. Да, изначальная формулировка - не лучшая, но в приведении к абсурдному варианту, вы ушли дальше оригинала.
P.S. Если я правильно понимаю то, что вы написали.

**2-й пункт.**
Обобщающее слово и однородные члены отвечают на один и тот же вопрос, согласуются в падежах. Исключением могут быть официально-деловые документы, в которых допускается использование именительного падежа во избежание искажения смысла.

**3-й пункт**. Перевозки - родовое понятие. Конечная доставка и доставка между регионами - видовые понятия. Последние являются подмножеством первого, обладают всеми его свойствами, но вместе с этим имеют и специфические. С логикой здесь все в порядке, не совсем точный (возможно), но абсолютно допустимый вариант. Точность и логичность - это характеристики речи (под речью имею в виду язык в действии). Говоря "не совсем точный", я оцениваю соответствие фактической семантики отображаемой действительности тому, что хочется выразить. Логика же - это структура и организация речи, смысловая сцепка языковых единиц. И еще раз - со вторым здесь все в порядке. Первое - могло бы быть и лучше.

Неточная речь может быть допустима к употреблению, т.к. с точки зрения передачи смысла (а это цель любой речи) нет непреодолимых препятствий к пониманию. А вот речь, в которой отсутствует логическая структура, не передает изначального смысла, а значит как она может быть допустима? Вы допускаете разговор с человеком, который не совсем точно выражается? Да, с кем не бывает. А допускаете возможность общения с человеком, речь которого является бессвязной и нелогичной? Вряд ли.
P.S. Это если под допустимостью понимаем возможность быть используемым в качестве инструмента для передачи смысла.

Answer (score 0):

**От Sharon-2023**

*Группа «Черкизово» производит и доставляет продукцию по двум основным сегментам: **(это) мясопереработка и птицеводство,** // а перевозки осуществляются как внутри городов в виде конечной доставки в розничные магазины, так и между регионами России.*

**Решение по Лопатину (метод блоков)**

**Два блока**, отношения сопоставительные, союз А.  На границе блоков ставим **запятую**, более сильных знаков не нужно.

**Первый блок.** Нет необходимости **в согласовании** по падежам,  ряд можно рассматривать как отдельное сообщение. Информация лучше воспринимается **в форме И.п.**

**Примечание**

Объем ответа небольшой, информативность **высокая**. Но можно ли применять **[правило Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)** к таким конструкциям?

**Можно,** потому что ответ соответствует **практике** письма и не противоречит **правилам** в обычном изложении. А ссылки можно найти в другой теме, если они необходимы. ***Главное — это само решение.***